# 導入したアプリの削除について

Tags: windows-10

プログラム関係とは少し違うので申し訳ないのですが、chromeを軽くするアプリとしてemptyを導入して削除したくなりファイルを削除したのですが、度々以下のようなエラー画面が出てきて困っております。コントロールパネルのアンインストール画面で確認してもemptyに関するアプリは存在しません。

windows script host
スクリプトファイル"C:WINDOWS￥system32¥¥empty.vbs"が見つかりません

Answer (score 0, accepted):

恐らく`empty.vbs`をタスクスケジューラで自動実行しているものと思われるので、設定を確認して該当のタスクを削除してみてください。

参考：
[マイクロソフトのツールでWindows10、7のメモリ開放と併せてタスクに入れてみた](http://zakk310.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/02/09/233854)